# where is placed the time configuration for --rotate in Sphinx?

Tags: configuration, indexing, sphinx, configuration-files

I want to use --rotate in sphinx for updating my index every 5 minutes, where is that number placed?

I this command for example

```
indexer --rotate --config /home/myuser/sphinx.conf --all
```

I have searched [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.htm) without luck, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexer program packaged with sphinx is not a daemon, nor will it run regularly on its own.  Instead, you need to use a scheduling program to do that.

For most flavors of Unix, you can just run the indexer using cron.

> $ crontab -e
>
> */5 * * * * /path/to/sphinx/bin/indexer --rotate --config /home/myuser/sphinx.conf --all